# Schur complement of the marginalized normal covariance matrix given joint Cholesky decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-distribution, marginal-distribution, cholesky-decomposition, schur-complement

Consider a multivariate normal distribution with covariance matrix $\Sigma$ of size $n \times n$, which can be written in terms of its lower triangular Cholesky decomposition $L$ as
$$\Sigma = L \cdot L^\intercal.$$

Consider the marginal joint normal distribution of $m$ of the original $n$ variables. The covariance matrix of the marginal distribution $\Sigma '$
can be written as:
$$\Sigma '= M (L L^\intercal) M^\intercal$$
where $M$ is a matrix of size $m\times n$ consisting of zeros and ones, so that $M$ is dropping the rows and columns corresponding to the unwanted $n-m$ variables.

Let us write $\Sigma'$ in block matrix form as $$\Sigma' = \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma'_{11} & \Sigma'_{12} \\
\Sigma_{12}^{'\intercal} & \Sigma'_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $\Sigma'_{11}$ is a $(m-1) \times (m-1)$ matrix, $\Sigma'_{12}$ is a $(m-1) \times 1$ vector and $\Sigma'_{22}$ is an single entry.

I want to derive a conditional normal distribution, therefore I need to compute the Schur complement of $\Sigma'_{22}$, i.e. $S = \Sigma'_{22}-\Sigma_{12}^{'\intercal}\Sigma_{11}^{'-1}\Sigma'_{12}$. I would like to express $S$ as a function of the entries of the Cholesky decomposition $L$ of the original matrix $\Sigma$ since the entries of $L$ have a statistical meaning in my model. Is it possible? A similar question was raised in this [Stack topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4489394/how-do-you-calculate-the-determinant-of-the-covariance-matrix-of-a-marginalized), but it remained unanswered.

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384769/proving-that-l-22l-22t-s-is-the-schur-complement-of-a-cholesky-factorizat), it is shown that we can relate the Schur complement of a matrix to its Cholesky factorization. Therefore, I tried to derive the Cholesky factorization of $\Sigma'$ as a rank $(n-m)$ downdate of Cholesky factorization of $\Sigma$, but this way seems rather complicated to follow (see [Julia's blog](https://docs.juliahub.com/NormalHermiteSplines/KDJDk/0.3.0/Updating-Cholesky-Factorization/)).

Any help would be much appreciated.